# Vuejs Boolean Attributes (Truthy and Falsy values)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-directives

I'm reading the Vuejs docs and get confused at some point when I was at the part of **Attribute Bindings** (link to the specific part : https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#boolean-attributes).

As far as I'm aware, in JavaScript, **empty strings** ("") are considered as **falsy**.

But, in Vuejs Docs:

> `<button :disabled="isButtonDisabled">Button</button>`
>
> > The **disabled** attribute will be included if **isButtonDisabled** has a **truthy value**. It will also be included if the value is an empty string, maintaining consistency with `<button disabled="">`. For other **falsy values** the attribute will be omitted.

Here, they evaluate the empty string as a **truthy value** !

If someone has an explanation ? it's something that we should be aware of, or it's just a choice of **Evan You** (creator of Vuejs), but based on what ?

Thanks.

Comment: It's being consistent with HTML.

Comment: at some point I interpreted it like that, so **disabled=""** will be parsed to **disabled**.  I'll accept that if it was official. Thanks @Pointy.

Comment: What do you mean "if it was official"? ... you ask why empty string is considered `truthy` in this case **in vue**, you quote the **vue docs** that state why it works that way, and yet you aren't sure if this explanation is **official**? How much more official can you get in explaining how vue works that vue docs?

Comment: @JaromandaX by official I mean if the core team of Vue have interpreted and approached it another way.

Comment: nope, you lost me - the documentation is all you need, if the core team of Vue interpreted it differently then the documentation would be useless since the code would not work as documented - I must be missing something basic, I just can't see why you are fighting against well documented, and completely logical behaviour

Comment: I'm not fighting.

Comment: sorry, fighting was the wrong word. Just seems the documentation isn't a good enough explanation of the behaviour. It's just how Vue works. :D

Comment: no, I wasn't even talking about the docs. Vue docs is amazing. Anyways...

Answer (score 2):

An empty string as value for the [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) HTML attribute, on elements which support it, is interpreted as a *truthy* value. This is the HTML standard.

```html
<input disabled />
<!-- exact equivalent of... -->
<input disabled="" />
<!-- exact equivalent of (in Vue template) -->
<input :disabled='""' />
<!-- exact equivalent of (in JSX) -->
<input disabled={""} />
```

When provided as a binding JavaScript expression, Vue will not include the attribute when the expression is falsy, except when it evaluates to empty string. In that case, Vue will include the attribute, without changing its value.

Why is the warning there?
Because empty string is typically interpreted as *falsy* value in JavaScript and they identified this as a potential source of subtle bugs

The attribute's behavior is not Vue team's decision. It's [W3C](https://www.w3.org/)'s decision.
So yeah, you can say it's *"official"*. It can't get any more *"official"* than that.

Comment: Yes, it's official now! hahaha. Thanks for your answer.